# Problems with linseed oil paint

Tags: paint

I have been trying to make my own linseed oil paint by adding pigments to boiled linseed oil. I have added around 500 g of titanium oxide per litre of BLO and around 125 g of zinc oxide (to help speed the drying). The paint mixes well and seems to go on ok but even after leaving to dry for a week or so, the colour can be rubbed of with a cloth (as in you can see white come off on a dark coloured cloth).

I tried to dilute the white I made with more oil and tried adding more zinc oxide (in two separate batches) but the problem still persists.

Any clues would be very welcome!

Thank you.

Comment: Might be better posed in [chemistry.stackexchange.com](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com).

Comment: LOL, @Caleb. My suggestion was here or Chemistry... Unfortunately, OP posted a new question instead of getting the old one migrated.

Comment: Some of this may simply come down to Just Wait Longer — imagine taking the pigment out of the equation and just applying that much BLO.... can you estimate how long it would take for it to stop being tacky? But in addition to that you're not making a very good paint with simple mixtures of oil and pigment. The proper production process for oil paint involves very heavy working of the mixture, to both 'wet' the pigment particles and to break up clumps smaller than you can see.

Comment: Thanks @Graphus. I have seen people using a muller to ensure wetting of pigment particles and so maybe it's as you say, there are tiny "clumps" of pigment in there that could come off the surface even once the BLO has dried. Could take me a while to mull enough paint for a couple of garage doors! Will see if I can come up with something.

Comment: *"Could take me a while"* Uh yeah, indeed!! You'll have forearms like Popeye when you're done, assuming your arms don't fall off first — seriously, ran this past a friend who's made paint and he estimates at least 2-3 full days o_O If you're sure you want to use linseed oil paint, you do know they make it? But if you decide to go ahead I wanted to caution about the rather extreme yellowing you can expect in due course. Whites are one of the colours historically made with greater care to help compensate for, or avoid, the natural yellowing of linseed oil (and better stuff than is used for BLO).

Comment: *"Will see if I can come up with something"* You're very likely to want to thin the paint for ease of brushing with turpentine or MS anyway, so you could try pre-wetting the pigment with the solvent (some of it, not the full amount) and the resultant wet paste is what you then blend into the oil, either in a blender or food processor. If you select the right oil none of the ingredients is toxic (the solvent evaporates entirely) so you could even subsequently use the appliance for its original purpose :-D

Comment: My wife bought a nice food processor just recently!! Thank you for the tips and advice.  I could buy the linseed paint but there is some part of me that wants to make it for some reason. All of the best lessons are learnt the hard way. I found a company called Brouns who sell natural oil paints and also have a couple of utube videos. If all else fails, I will leave it to the professionals.